# How to make a proper .json file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

All I want to do is create a basic app converting degrees Celsius to Fahrenheit. That being said I need to store the temperature data using Data.json. It's a small list of 5 different temperatures But for some reason I keep getting an error at the bottom of my list along 2 commas.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong with my Data.json file???

Thanks,

```
[
 {
   "1": 23,
   "2": 30,
   "3": 40,
   "4": 41,
   "5": 19,



 },
]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[
 {
   "1": 23,
   "2": 30,
   "3": 40,
   "4": 41,
   "5": 19
 }
]
```

Kindly use https://jsoneditoronline.org/ in future for easier debugging.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely keep on using the json editor.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to this link [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and check checkbox fix JSON

[image]

**VALID JSON**

```
[ 
   { 
      "1":23,
      "2":30,
      "3":40,
      "4":41,
      "5":19
   }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

In Json, you do not need to add a comma after the last item in an array [...] or property in an object {...}.

Answer (score -1):

The comma denotes that there are further entries. So the last entry shouldn't have any comma as per the syntax.

> JSON syntax is derived from JavaScript object notation syntax:
>
> - Data is in name/value pairs
> - Data is separated by commas
> - Curly braces hold objects
> - Square brackets hold arrays